# How to keep track of mapnotes?

Tags: tools, map-making

I want to run an Eberron setting game, and I'd like to use the Eberron map, which I have as a high-resolution png, but be able to add quick notes and such as the game progresses. Something similar to the way you can in Google Maps.

I have already considered using the Google Maps API, but I wanted to look for a simpler solution first.

The existing map can be seen [here](http://images.wikia.com/eberron/images/f/f4/D&D_-_4th_Edition_-_Eberron_Map_Khorvaire.jpg).

Comment: As this is a recommendation question, please adhere to both the [FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760). In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience or cited references to others' experiences. Just throwing out tool names you've heard of is a junk answer.

Comment: Also, my personal thoughts - please don't just propose every image manipulation tool known to man, he wants an easy map annotation solution. Paint.NET, GIMP, Office, etc. are obvious and poor solutions.

Comment: tool recs are now off-topic (ca. August 2015)--I've tried to minimally re-work this according to [these principles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185486/311001). If you don't think I've preserved the core of your question please feel free to revert my changes (by clicking on the "edited ... ago" link).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [Realm Works](http://www.wolflair.com/realmworks) by Lone Wolf.

It allows you to add pins to your maps and chain content together with hyperlinked tags. You can see [the pins in the map view screenshots](http://www.wolflair.com/realmworks/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/12/mapfornavigation_web.png).

Comment: It has been a while, but I decided to mark this the answer. Realm Works is a very handy tool, and it really makes DM-/GM-ing a lot easier. It takes some time to get used to the interface, but once you do it is great.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a wiki (say [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) since it can be used from [vim](http://www.vim.org/) and [git](http://git-scm.com/)) and [image map tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) with mouse-over notes/hints.  Anyone in the group can then link NPCs, locations, history, game journal, and all those things. Of course, setting the map is hassle.

*Note that mouse-over will not work on mobile devices.*

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with a desktop application, then this works well:

You'll need to install [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) - it's free, in every sense of the term, and is available for most platforms.

Open your image in LibreOffice Draw, and save it in ODF Format for use as an editable Draw file.

Then you should be able to add annotations through the Insert>Comment menu option.  These take the form of numbers on the map until you click on them, at which point they open a post-it-note-type box to write in.

You could also use layers to add additional features on the map, such as hidden locations, regional borders, or even a grid overlay.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can imagine is making the map into a PDF and then use a program like Adobe Reader or PDF-XChange Viewer to write comments. Best thing is that you're not stuck with esoteric file formats or expensive specialized solutions.

For portability, use a flash drive or save to Dropbox (or similar).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind programming a bit and Javascript doesn't scare you, perhaps [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org/) is the right tool for you.

Comment: I'm not sure programming in *anything* quite fits most peoples' notion of a "simpler solution."

Comment: Note that the OP considered using Google Map API, which is a programming interface.